# Program wont print out amount of characters that are in a file

Tags: c++, ifstream

Hello all I have to make a program that counts all the characters that are in a given text file
I have no errors when I compile it. But when I run it it prompts and takes the name of my file but then ends. Here is my code.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include"counterType.h"
#include <fstream>
#define MAX 1000
using namespace std;
void countchar(counterType intchar, ifstream& indata);
int main()
{
    ifstream indata;
    counterType intchar;
    cout << "What file would you like to read?" << endl;
    string filename = "empty"; 
    cin >> filename;
    indata.open(filename);
    return 0;
    countchar(intchar, indata);
    intchar.displayCounter();
}

void countchar(counterType intchar, ifstream& indata)
{   
    string x;
    indata >> x;
    while(!indata.eof()) {
        indata >> x;
        intchar.incrementCounter(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `return 0;`

Comment: What is `counterType`? What is `countchar`? What is `incrementCounter()`? Are you aware that a `string` is _not_ the same as a character? That don't involve reading all of it? Why do you `return` halfway through your program? Why don't you just use one of the traditional methods for determining the size of a file?

Comment: You are passing a copy of `counterType` to `counterchar()` so any changes (counts) made are not reflected upon return

Comment: Also note that your usage of `while(!indata.eof())` is [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons).

Comment: Increase the warning level on your compiler. Some compilers can help you to spot things like this. `g++` and `clang++` have `-Wall -Wextra` that catches a lot.

Comment: Unrelated: If you put the function `countchar` above `main` you don't need that prototype above `main` that you have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
    return 0;
```

makes it return from the function and prevents executing lines after that. You should remove that to execute `countchar(intchar, indata);` and `intchar.displayCounter();`.

Comment: Thanks I didnt realize that I put it in the wrong area